# Manipulate for Electric Field

Tags: performance-tuning, manipulate

I'm kind of new to *Mathematica* but I'm getting the hang of it slowly. Anyways, I'm trying to do a project on the electric field of two particles so my professor helped me with this code (sorry in advanced for the length)

```
Clear[x, y, lof, Δθ];
V = -1/Sqrt[(x + 1)^2 + y^2] + 1/Sqrt[(x - 1)^2 + y^2];
Grad[V, {x, y, z}] // Simplify;
Ex[x_, y_] = -Grad[V, {x, y, z}][[1]];
Ey[x_, y_] = -Grad[V, {x, y, z}][[2]];

Emag[x_, y_] = 
  Sqrt[Ex[x, y]^2 + Ey[x, y]^2] // Simplify // PowerExpand;
lof = {};
Δθ = 10 °;

For[θ = 0 °, θ < 360 °,
 x0 = 1 + .2*Cos[θ];
 y0 = .2*Sin[θ];
 Δs = .01;
 pts = {};
 nsteps = 1000;
 AppendTo[pts, {x0, y0}];
 For[n = 1, n <= nsteps,
  Δx = Ex[x0, y0]/Emag[x0, y0]*Δs;
  Δy = Ey[x0, y0]/Emag[x0, y0]*Δs;
  x = x0 + Δx;
  y = y0 + Δy;
  If[Sqrt[(x - 1)^2 + y^2] > .2, AppendTo[pts, {x, y}]];
  x0 = x;
  y0 = y;
  n = n + 1;
  ];
 AppendTo[lof, Line[pts]];
 θ = θ + Δθ;
 ]
For[ θ = 0 °, θ < 360 °,
 x0 = -1 + .2*Cos[θ];
 y0 = .2*Sin[θ];
 Δs = .01;
 pts = {};
 nsteps = 1000;
 AppendTo[pts, {x0, y0}];
 For[n = 1, n <= nsteps,
  Δx = -Ex[x0, y0]/Emag[x0, y0]*Δs;
  Δy = -Ey[x0, y0]/Emag[x0, y0]*Δs;
  x = x0 + Δx;
  y = y0 + Δy;
  If[Sqrt[(x - 1)^2 + y^2] > .2, AppendTo[pts, {x, y}]];
  x0 = x;
  y0 = y;
  n = n + 1;
  ];
 AppendTo[lof, Line[pts]];
 θ = θ + Δθ;
 ]
ContourPlot[V, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
 Contours -> Table[z, {z, -2, 2, .2}],
 ContourShading -> False,
 ContourStyle -> {{Black, Dashing[{.01}]}},
 Frame -> False, 
 Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[7], Blue, Point[{-1, 0}], Red, 
   Point[{1, 0}], Yellow, lof}, Background -> Gray, PlotRange -> All]
```

The output should be:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is do a manipulate function. One that will just move the position of the left particle. So in the code I just want to change the three-starred one (`***1***`) into a variable for the manipulate function.

```
 V = -1/Sqrt[(x + ***1***)^2 + y^2] + 1/Sqrt[(x - 1)^2 + y^2];
```

But I can't figure out the correct syntax. Could someone lend a helping hand? Thank you!

Comment: The code you have is pretty slow, but fortunately the interactivity you are looking for is also very easily realizable by simply pre-rendering a `Table` of plots in which the charge location is varied step-wise. That list of images can then be quickly manipulated, most easily by using `ListAnimate`.

Comment: You definitely should write your code as a `Module`, making sure to end lines with `;`. Once you've wrapped it inside a function with all variables localized, the displacement of the charge can be introduced as a function parameter.

Comment: [This wolfram activity](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ElectricFieldsForPairsOfCylindersOrSpheres/) might also provide some helpful guidance.